# WordPress Advanced Custom Fields - Using Select Field In An Array & Modify Array Elements

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a WordPress website. I am using the ACF Pro plugin. I have a select field and I want to assign a second value to each option. The first value is being used as a heading. The second is a percentage figure (at the moment just a string). This will be used as a label as well as a data-percentage value. I cant get the select values to work with my array. Here is my code.

```
 <h4>Qualification: <?php echo $array_test; ?></h4>
```

And then the array;

```
        <?php
            $myArray = array('$array_tests');
            $myArray[0]= '20%';
            $myArray[1]= '40%';
            $myArray[2]= '60%';
            $myArray[3]= '80%';
            $myArray[4]= '100%';

            echo "<h1> Test:";  
            echo $myArray;
            echo "<h1>";                    

        ?>
```

And finally using the modified array's output as a data-percentage;

```
<div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="<?php echo $myArray ?>%">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have assigned this variable to my select custom field.

```
$staff_qualification    = get_sub_field('qualification');
```

I use it for the title.

```
<h4>Qualification: <?php echo $staff_qualification; ?></h4>
```

And I created a switch so that I now have a new value assigned to each option from the dropdown select.

```
        <?php

        switch ($staff_qualification) {
        case "NVQ Level 1":
          $staff_qualification_percentage = 20;
          break;
        case "NVQ Level 2":
          $staff_qualification_percentage = 40;
          break;
        case "NVQ Level 3":
          $staff_qualification_percentage = 60;
          break;
        case "NVQ Level 4":
          $staff_qualification_percentage = 80;
          break;                                
        case "Degree In Childcare":
          $staff_qualification_percentage = 100;
          break;
        }                      
    ?>
```

And now I echo the variable used in each case as my data-percentage value.

```
<div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="<?php echo $staff_qualification_percentage; ?>%">
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't echo arrays, but do a print_r($array);

Point no. 2: You are trying to show $array_test but you are not declaring it beforehand.

So, to echo the percentage inside the HTML, you should do something like this:

```
<?php
            $myArray = array('$array_tests');
            $myArray[0]= '20%';
            $myArray[1]= '40%';
            $myArray[2]= '60%';
            $myArray[3]= '80%';
            $myArray[4]= '100%';

            echo "<h1> Test:";  
            print_r ($myArray);
            echo "<h1>";                    

        ?>

<div class="skillbar clearfix" data-percent="<?php echo $myArray[1] ?>%">
```

Here we can echo because you are trying to get one value of the array, and not the whole values.

This should echo 40% inside the markup "data-percent", however I think this type of CSS bars don't allow the % symbol inside, which means you just need to echo the "40".

Comment: Hi @nunorbatista thanks for your help! This is great but isnt quite working. Only thing is I dont know which item from the array will be needed as the percentage value. This is giving me this code for my title now;

    `Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 40 [2] => 60 [3] => 80 [4] => 100 )`

And works for the percentage value but only when I hardcode which item I want. Is it possible for this to work without specifying  which item I need?

Comment: Hi @StuartNelson. That is another problem, your array has that values inside and by following some external condition it should display the required value. It's impossible to work without specifying which item you need, otherwise the code would have to guess the value to show :) My reply answers to your question so I would ask you to accept it. Cheers!

Comment: I guess I could use a switch? And assign a new variable to each case and echo the new variable as my value for the percentage value.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding the problem you're facing. You were requesting a way to show a value inside the HTML in order to build the "skillbar" with CSS, and that is done. You presented an array with multiple values inside that I don't know where they come from or how they are created. You need to see the source of the values in order to know which one to show.

Comment: the values coem from a custom field that is a select dropdown. I've solved this by using a switch. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @StuartNelson I'm glad to help. I didn't knew where the values come from, I imagined it came from some kind of accomplishment meter and I was wrong. If my answer helped you, please accept it. Cheers